# How to confirm connectivity to postgres database from a container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, prisma, hoppscotch

I am trying to build [Hoppscotch](https://docs.hoppscotch.io/), an Open-source API development Ecosystem locally on my Mac, so I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.hoppscotch.io/documentation/self-host/community-edition/install-and-build).

I have installed and set all the prerequisites, and now I am trying to configure the environment.

When I reach to run the following container:

```bash
docker run -p 3170:3170 --env-file .env hoppscotch-backend
```

I am getting the following error (I divide it in 2 parts)

**Part 1**

```
Initialize PubSub
/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@4.16.2_prisma@4.16.2/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:108
You may have to run ${S("prisma generate")} for your changes to take effect.`,this.config.clientVersion);return r}
parseEngineResponse(r){if(!r)throw new oe("Response from the Engine was empty",{clientVersion:this.config.
clientVersion});try{return JSON.parse(r)}catch{throw new oe("Unable to JSON.parse response from engine",
{clientVersion:this.config.clientVersion})}}convertDatasources(r){let n=Object.create(null);for(let{name:i,url:o}of r)n
[i]=o;return n}async loadEngine(){if(!this.engine){this.QueryEngineConstructor||(this.library=await this.libraryLoader.
loadLibrary(),this.QueryEngineConstructor=this.library.QueryEngine);try{let r=new WeakRef(this);this.engine=new this.
QueryEngineConstructor({datamodel:this.datamodel,env:process.env,logQueries:this.config.logQueries??!1,
ignoreEnvVarErrors:!0,datasourceOverrides:this.datasourceOverrides,logLevel:this.logLevel,configDir:this.config.cwd,
engineProtocol:this.engineProtocol},n=>{r.deref()?.logger(n)}),ca++}catch(r){let n=r,i=this.parseInitError(n.message);
throw typeof i=="string"?n:new Q(i.message,this.config.clientVersion,i.error_code)}}}logger(r){let n=this.
parseEngineResponse(r);if(!!n){if("span"in n){this.config.tracingHelper.createEngineSpan(n);return}n.level=n?.level.
toLowerCase()??"unknown",Bp(n)?this.logEmitter.emit("query",{timestamp:new Date,query:n.query,params:n.params,
duration:Number(n.duration_ms),target:n.module_path}):Vp(n)?this.loggerRustPanic=new be(this.getErrorMessageWithLink(`$
{n.message}: ${n.reason} in ${n.file}:${n.line}:${n.column}`),this.config.clientVersion):this.logEmitter.emit(n.level,
{timestamp:new Date,message:n.message,target:n.module_path})}}getErrorMessageWithLink(r){return sa({platform:this.
platform,title:r,version:this.config.clientVersion,engineVersion:this.versionInfo?.commit,database:this.config.
activeProvider,query:this.lastQuery})}parseInitError(r){try{return JSON.parse(r)}catch{}return r}parseRequestError(r)
{try{return JSON.parse(r)}catch{}return r}on(r,n){r==="beforeExit"?this.beforeExitListener=n:this.logEmitter.on(r,n)}
async start(){if(await this.libraryInstantiationPromise,await this.libraryStoppingPromise,this.libraryStartingPromise)
return qe(`library already starting, this.libraryStarted: ${this.libraryStarted}`),this.libraryStartingPromise;if(this.
libraryStarted)return;let r=async()=>{qe("library starting");try{let n={traceparent:this.config.tracingHelper.
getTraceParent()};await this.engine?.connect(JSON.stringify(n)),this.libraryStarted=!0,qe("library started")}catch(n)
{let i=this.parseInitError(n.message);throw typeof i=="string"?n:new Q(i.message,this.config.clientVersion,i.
error_code)}finally{this.libraryStartingPromise=void 0}};return this.libraryStartingPromise=this.config.tracingHelper.
runInChildSpan("connect",r),this.libraryStartingPromise}async stop(){if(await this.libraryStartingPromise,await this.
executingQueryPromise,this.libraryStoppingPromise)return qe("library is already stopping"),this.libraryStoppingPromise;
if(!this.libraryStarted)return;let r=async()=>{await new Promise(i=>setTimeout(i,5)),qe("library stopping");let n=
{traceparent:this.config.tracingHelper.getTraceParent()};await this.engine?.disconnect(JSON.stringify(n)),this.
libraryStarted=!1,this.libraryStoppingPromise=void 0,qe("library stopped")};return this.libraryStoppingPromise=this.
config.tracingHelper.runInChildSpan("disconnect",r),this.libraryStoppingPromise}async getDmmf(){await this.start();let 
r=this.config.tracingHelper.getTraceParent(),n=await this.engine.dmmf(JSON.stringify({traceparent:r}));return this.
config.tracingHelper.runInChildSpan({name:"parseDmmf",internal:!0},()=>JSON.parse(n))}version(){return this.
versionInfo=this.library?.version(),this.versionInfo?.version??"unknown"}debugPanic(r){return this.library?.debugPanic
(r)}async request(r,{traceparent:n,interactiveTransaction:i}){qe(`sending request, this.libraryStarted: ${this.
libraryStarted}`);let o=JSON.stringify({traceparent:n}),s=JSON.stringify(r);try{await this.start(),this.
executingQueryPromise=this.engine?.query(s,o,i?.id),this.lastQuery=s;let a=this.parseEngineResponse(await this.
executingQueryPromise);if(a.errors)throw a.errors.length===1?this.buildQueryError(a.errors[0]):new oe(JSON.stringify(a.
errors),{clientVersion:this.config.clientVersion});if(this.loggerRustPanic)throw this.loggerRustPanic;return{data:a,
elapsed:0}}catch(a){if(a instanceof Q)throw a;if(a.code==="GenericFailure"&&a.message?.startsWith("PANIC:"))throw new
be(this.getErrorMessageWithLink(a.message),this.config.clientVersion);let l=this.parseRequestError(a.message);throw
typeof l=="string"?a:new oe(`${l.message}
```

**Part 2**

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432`

Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`5432`.
    at r (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@4.16.2_prisma@4.16.2/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:108:2574)
    at async Proxy.onModuleInit (/usr/src/app/packages/hoppscotch-backend/dist/prisma/prisma.service.js:20:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async callModuleInitHook (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@9.2.1_@nestjs+common@9.2.1_@nestjs+platform-express@9.2.1_reflect-metadata@0.1.13_rxjs@7.6.0/node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-module-init.hook.js:43:5)
    at async NestApplication.callInitHook (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@9.2.1_@nestjs+common@9.2.1_@nestjs+platform-express@9.2.1_reflect-metadata@0.1.13_rxjs@7.6.0/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.js:210:13)
    at async NestApplication.init (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@9.2.1_@nestjs+common@9.2.1_@nestjs+platform-express@9.2.1_reflect-metadata@0.1.13_rxjs@7.6.0/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:97:9)
    at async NestApplication.listen (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@9.2.1_@nestjs+common@9.2.1_@nestjs+platform-express@9.2.1_reflect-metadata@0.1.13_rxjs@7.6.0/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:155:33)
    at async bootstrap (/usr/src/app/packages/hoppscotch-backend/dist/main.js:40:5) {
  clientVersion: '4.16.2',
  errorCode: 'P1001'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

While honestly I didn't understand the first part at all, I didn't know where to start reading it to debug the issue, I understood that Prisma having connectivity issue to the postgres server.

I tried buildiing postgres client by Prisma sepearately, and I could connect to the database normally and create tables with few entries as well.

I have spent the whole day researching, that it is even difficult to list all the solutions that I've tried, but I tried everything from reinstalling postgres again to even changing node's version, but nothing helped.

Since my understanding is that this is a postgres connectivity issue, my question is how to this postgres connectivity issue, but I would appreciate any hint about what else might be causing the. problem

Answer (score 0):

Some hints just regarding docker/postgres (not regarding prisma/hoppscotch).
Container with three images, one is postgres, another image wants to connect.

I've added

```
ENV POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

to my postgres/Dockerfile so that another image in that container is allowed to access postgres.

In YML I've added

```
healthcheck:
    test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d (db name) -U (user name)" ]
    interval: 10s
    timeout: 5s
    retries: 10
```

to the postgres service and

```
depends_on:
    postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
```

to the other service.